# CSS, how to center vertically text inside an overlay in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, overlay

I have an overlay, used to show a spinner (an Angular material component) and a text. This overlay is all over the page and you can't click the elements below.

The spinner is in the middle of the page, and I want the "loading" text to be vertically aligned with the spinner, at the bottom of it-, and of course, to be centered horizzontally.

here are my HTML code and CSS styles:

```
<div id="overlay" [style.display]="this.showOverlay">
   <div id="overlay-spinner">
      <mat-spinner [diameter]="80" color="accent"></mat-spinner>
   </div>
   <div id="overlay-text">
      <span>Loading ...</span>
   </div>
</div>


#overlay {
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
    height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
    z-index: 1; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different 
    order for other elements */
    cursor: default; /* Add a pointer on hover */
}

#overlay-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#overlay-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-65%,-50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-65%,-50%);
}
```

You have not to care about [] attributes inside the tags because those are Angular code. They are used to set spinner properties or to show the entire overlay.

I tried with position absolute, top 65% and left 50% but the spinner and the text are not well aligned. How Can I do ?

Comment: Try either text-align:center or margin: 0 auto;

Comment: do you mean to add those rules inside overlay-text, right ? Have I to cancel position, top and left ?

Comment: Yes inside overlay test, remove left, you can use top to position the div's top margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your best shot is display:flex on the overlay with it's direction and alignments (see snippet below). On flex you can read more [here in this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) quite comprehensive and great guide. I hope this is what you expected to achieve!

p.s.: I used 'spinner is here' to make sure it is visible

p.s.2.: Do not let your eyes trick you, with the '...' at the end of 'Loading' it is actually centered right below the spinner text

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1; 
    cursor: default; 
}

#overlay-text {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" [style.display]="this.showOverlay">
   <div id="overlay-spinner">
     <p>spinner is here</p>
   </div>
   <div id="overlay-text">
      <span>Loading ...</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer

Comment: I'm a stackoverflow noobie, how you make the snipper runnable ?

Comment: @Fjordo when entering an answer there is a tiny icon to insert a code snippet (next to insert image and hyperlink and formatting). There will be a popup where you can enter html+css+JS, see the result and also easily add a few generally used libraries such as AngularJS or jQuery.

Comment: @Fjordo and if you are also new to positioning in CSS then I HIGHLY recommend getting familiar with flexbox it will save many hours of work and limitless amount of frustration for you. It is quite easy to use, very intuitive and works like a charm in modern UI design (including being responsive and stuff like this)

Comment: Thanks, by the way, Did you cancel the #overlay-spinner rules ? i can't see in your snippet, but there is the id attribute in the tag still

Comment: With the flex settings on the #overlay wrapper div there is no need for any positioning of the children (spinner and text). Also if you are only using IDs for styling then I would suggest using classes instead. IDs are generally for more specific uses like targeting a DOM element with JS so identifying it for further use. Classes on the other hand are more reusable (several DOM elements can have the same class while an ID is supposed to be unique to one element). So if you are using IDs for identification then it is fine, otherwise if it's only styling then I recommend using classes.

Comment: Yes, I use ID because of Angular identification to target the element and to make it visible

Comment: Great, just wanted to make sure! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just place your loading text into your overlay-spinner div.

```html
<div id="overlay" [style.display]="this.showOverlay">
   <div id="overlay-spinner">
      <mat-spinner [diameter]="80" color="accent"></mat-spinner>
      <span id="overlay-text">Loading ...</span>
   </div>
</div>


#overlay {
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
    height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
    z-index: 1; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different 
    order for other elements */
    cursor: default; /* Add a pointer on hover */
}

#overlay-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#overlay-text {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I obtain the text in the right "corner" of the spinner.